# Conditional types with union types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Say I have a generic type declaration

```
type P1<T> = Promise<T>;
```

Then the type `T1 = P1<string | number | (() => void)>;` yields `Promise<string | number | (() => void)>` as expected.

If I want to narrow down the type to not accept functions, I'd declare

```
type P2<T> = T extends Function ? never : Promise<T>;
```

However, then `type T2 = P2<string | number | (() => void)>` suddenly yields `Promise<string> | Promise<number>` and not `Promise<string | number>` as I would have expected.

I know that this is according to the [specs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) of typescript. However, is there any way to extend `P2` to make this yield `Promise<string | number>` nevertheless **and** prohibit `P2` to be used for function types?

I also tried to use a "naked" type parameter [T]

```
type P3<T> = [T] extends Function ? never : Promise<T>;
```

This yields `type T3 = P3<string | number | (() => void)>` as least as `Promise<string | number | (() => void)>` but the function type was not removed, as intended.

Is it at all possible what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
type P3<T> = Promise<Exclude<T, () => any>>

type Y = P3<(() => void) | number | string> // will be Promise<string | number>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTAHgCoD4oF4pKhAHsCAOwBMBnKAMQFdCBjYASwHtCoB+KQiANwgCcoALlh8mAWwakIyFAG4AsACgloSLADMMjCPGTpAUVy0ANlWLSkAGigAKAJQY0AQ0IgUKJZ8WroADW3wCDb2jlDcTAzEDgA+nFRiAEb8ULGkwHwMhADmHt7g0ACaAZrBDuho4ZExcYnJqemZOUA)

Comment: Thx! Type P3<T> = Promise<Exclude<T, Function>> does it even make more generic for arbitrary functions...